# Как заставить android не уничтожать fragment / activity при нехватке ресурсов?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, xamarin

Добрый день, господа.
Пишу приложение под android и столкнулся вот с какой проблемой... После того как мое приложение открыто, я открываю другие ресурсоемкие приложения: игры, браузер и т.д., тогда android уничтожает в моем приложении активный fragment / activity, освобождая т.о. ресурсы для системы. Потом я снова пытаюсь открыть приложение, но оно перегружается и крашется. Описание ошибки:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{my_app/md530ee4884bf1bb4f3619af03b33af6888.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@7b3d21a:
>   Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131099824 at offset 460  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel
>   android.os.Parcel@7b3d21a: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131099824
>   at offset 460     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2340)    at
>   android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2675)   at
>   android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1967)   at
>   android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2321)     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)  at
>   android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)   at
>   android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:856)   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:997)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2041)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:163)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:331)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
>     at md530ee4884bf1bb4f3619af03b33af6888.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native
>   Method)   at
>   md530ee4884bf1bb4f3619af03b33af6888.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>     ... 9 more

Как заставить android не уничтожать fragment / activity? Или может быть какое-то другое решение? Пишу на **C# Xamarin**, но на **Java** код практически идентичен.

Вызов фрагмента из **MainActivity**:

```
SupportFragment fragment = new ItemCharacteristicsFragment();
var fragmentManager = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
fragmentManager.Replace(Resource.Id.flContent, fragment);
fragmentManager.AddToBackStack(null);
fragmentManager.CommitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Сам фрагмент:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using SupportFragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;
using ShopMobile;
using Android.Text;

namespace StozharyApp.Classes
{
    class ItemCharacteristicsFragment : SupportFragment
    {
        public ItemElement Item { get; set; }

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ItemCharacteristics, container, false);
            TextView txtCharacteristics = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCharacteristics);
            txtCharacteristics.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml(Item.Desc);

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему вы для завершения транзакции используете метод CommitAllowingStateLoss вместо Commit? Допускать потерю состояния плохая идея, если с методом Commit у вас приложение начинает крашится и предлагать использовать CommitAllowingStateLoss, то с вероятностью 99,9% вы где то не там производите эту транзакцию.

Comment: Возможно что-то делаю не так, потому как опыта программирования под андроид еще маловато. Пока нашел единственное решение, чтобы приложение не крашилось при восстановлении использовать CommitAllowingStateLoss, по это не спасает, когда фрагмент уничтожается системой, а потом не восстанавливается.

Comment: ну так покажите как вы фрагмент в активити создаёте, а то у вас только кусок непосредственно создания транзакции, а где и как вы его используете непонятно, а от этого многое зависит.

Comment: так вроде все показал, код самого фрагмента и при нажатии на кнопку вызываю фрагмент. Единсвенное, что не указал, так это то, что в конструкторе сразу инициализирую свойтсво класса фрагмента локальной переменной: SupportFragment fragment = new ItemCharacteristicsFragment({Item = myItem}).

Comment: воот, а зря не указали, запомните, что если не хотите проблем с восстановлением состояний никогда не передавайте ничего во фрагмент напрямую через конструктор или присвоение значений напрямую в поле. Любые параметры должны передаваться во фрагмент ТОЛЬКО через Bundle в метод setArguments и соответственно все эти параметры должны быть примитивами, строками, массивами, списками, Parcelable или Serializable. Да, это не удобно, но таков андройд.

Comment: а дело всё в том что при восстановлении состояния фрагмент будет пересоздан не вашим кодом а менаджером фрагментов и сделает он это через конструктор по умолчанию (который без параметров), и соответственно ничего что вы передавали через конструктор с параметрами или напрямую инициализируя поля не восстановится, сохраниться только содержимое получаемое через getArguments (на ксамарин наверное этот метод будет виден как свойство Arguments)

Comment: Спасибо за расширенный ответ, теперь понятно свою ошибку. Я так понимаю свой класс передавать необходимо через сериализованную строку? Могли бы Вы показать код передачи параметров во фрагмент с последующим воосстановлением? И потом использовать все-таки Commit() вместо CommitAllowingStateLoss()?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по стек трейсу у вас при восстановлении состояния активити или фрагмента не удаётся восстановить какой то Parcelable объект, скорее всего вы при предаче параметров/аргументов в активити/фрагмент или при сохранении его состояния использовали какой то плохо реализованный наследник от Parcelable. Проверьте что вы передаёте и сохраняете.

Comment: я вообще не сохраняю состояние фрагмента, в Android SDK говориться, что это делается автоматичесики при добавлении фрагмента в Back Stack. Как можно программно реализовать механизм сохранения фрагмента?

Comment: автоматически сохраняется только внутреннее состояние, а так же некоторые параметры для вьюх у которых задан в разметке id, если вам нужно сохранять содержимое полей класса или ещё что то, то вам это нужно реализовать самостоятельно, сохранять в методе onSaveInstanceState, а восстанавливать например в onCreate из параметра savedInstanceState.

Answer (score 1):

Единственный вариант восстанавливать фрагмент в `onSaveInstanceState`

### Сохранение в Activity

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    ...
}
```

Вытаскивайте в самой `Activity` в методе `onCreate`, проверьте на `null` переменную `Bundle savedInstanceState`, если пуста, то загружайте новые данные, если нет - восстанавливайте из `Bundle`.
Тот же код для `fragment` только восстановление в методе `onActivityCreated`

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю точно, поможет вам или нет, но у фрагмента есть метод setRetainInstance(boolean), и если его вызвать с аргументом true, то у фрагмента не будут вызываться методы onCreate и onDestroy, т.е. фрагмент будет воссоздан а не создан заново.

Вызывайте его в методе фрагмента onCreate.

Comment: Уже пробовал так делать, не помогает! В Andoid SDK нашел инфу, что setRetainInstance не работает если используется addToBackStack().

Answer (score 0):

мне помогло
`getUserVisibleHint()`
можно вызвать в любом месте кода фрагмента. Метод возвратит true если контент виден пользователю